# Using RSpec with Factory Girl and get a can't define singleton error

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, factory-bot

I'm using Factory Girl to generate test date in order to mock a connection to an ldap server (because I don't want the application to make a real ldap connection each time in order to successfully run my tests).

I want to mock this connection and confirm that this occurred successfully.

My factory girl data is:

**/factories/connections.rb**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :connection do
    host "just-ln1-wdc03.company.qube"
    port 389
    base "DC=company,DC=qube"
    username "cat@company.qube"
    password "cats123"
  end
end
```

and my Rspec test is:

**authenticate_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "#is_authenticated_by_ldap" do 
  let(:connection) {FactoryGirl.build(:connection)}

  it "queries ldap server and returns success" do
    allow(:connection).to receive(:is_authenticated_by_ldap).with("cat@company.qube", "cats123").and_return(true)
  end
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'factory_girl'
require_relative './factories/connections.rb'

RSpec.configure do|config|
...
```

**authenticate.rb**

```
def is_authenticated_by_ldap(credentials)
  full_username = credentials[0] + EXTENSION #EXTENSION = "company.com"
  ldap = Net::LDAP.new  :host => "just-ln1-wdc03.company.qube", # your LDAP host name or IP goes here,
                        :port => 389, # your LDAP host port goes here,
                        # :encryption => :simple_tls,
                        :base => "DC=company,DC=qube", # the base of your AD tree goes here,
                        :auth => {
                          :method => :simple,
                          :username => full_username, # a user w/sufficient privileges to read from AD goes here,
                          :password => credentials[1] # the user's password goes here
                        }   
        
  is_authorized = ldap.bind
  return is_authorized
end
```

parameters passed to the `is_authenticated_by_ldap` method are essentially username and password effectively credentials[0] and credentials[1] respectively.

When I run this `rspec spec/authenticate_spec.rb`, I receive the following error:

```
Authenticate
←[32m  authenticates a user on qube server←[0m
  #is_authenticated_by_ldap
←[31m    queries ldap server and returns success (FAILED - 1)←[0m

Failures:
  1) Authenticate#is_authenticated_by_ldap queries ldap server and returns success
     ←[31mFailure/Error: allow(:connection).to receive(:is_authenticated_by_ldap).with("cats@company.qube", "cats123").and_return(true)←[0m
     ←[31mTypeError:←[0m
     ←[31m  can't define singleton←[0m
```

## UPDATE

I believe I have answered my own question and have posted an explanation here as someone else may have this problem and seek a solution like I did:

RSpec 3.0 has a feature called an instance double which takes a class name or object as it's first argument and then verifies that any methods being stubbed would be present and execute on an instance of that class.

So in my case because I had an Authenticate module which handled my authentication feature, I created a dummy class in my Rspec test, which also included the said module.(see code below)

## authenticate_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

```
class Dummy
    include Authenticate
end 

describe Authenticate do

        let(:dummy_class) {Dummy.new.authenticate}
        let(:credentials) {FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:credentials)}

            it "authenticates a user on qube server" do 

                expect(:dummy_class).to be

            end 


        describe "#is_authenticated_by_ldap" do 

            it "queries ldap server and returns successful connection" do

                dummy = instance_double("Dummy")
                
                allow(dummy).to receive(:is_authenticated_by_ldap).with(:credentials).and_return(true)
            
                expect(dummy.is_authenticated_by_ldap(:credentials)).to be(true)

            end

    end


end

#spec/factories/credentials.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :credentials do
    username "cats@company.com"
    password "cats123"
  end
end
```

and defined test data using factory_girl (username and password) to pass as a parameter of the is_authenticated_by_ldap method.(this method confirms a successful connection to the ldap server or not). Using RSpec 3.0 syntax, if you use stubs/mocks, the allow method with a receive matcher, tells the fake object to return a value in response to a given message/method. In my case, I would expect the test to pass (successful ldap connection) or fail (unsuccessful ldap connection). To confirm that my mock worked correctly and wasn't a false positive, test data defined by factory girl gem(and not existing on the ldap server) was used and the test passed. I also commented out the source code for the method and reran the test and it failed as expected.

Comment: answered my own question as this may help someone who had a similar problem to me.

Comment: It's great that you shared your answer to your own question, but it would help all users (both those seeking an answer and those interested in answer the question themselves) if you would post the information as an actual "answer".